# iOS7 iPad view is loaded in landscape mode instead of portrait mode

Tags: ipad, ios7

On iOS7, i have a viewController added as a subview to the root view controller like so:

```
[self.view insertSubview:self.tutorialViewController.view aboveSubview:self.accessoriesView];
```

What happens is in viewDidLoad and in viewDidAppear, it loads with landscape mode dimensions, instead of portrait.

This also happens on iOS6 and bellow, but somehow it gets resized so this is not an issue. It seems that self.view.frame is not always reliable: http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=85

What could be the cause of this and how can i fix it?